# FastImageCache on iOS using Copied images

Tags: ios, image

As per documentation :

Color Copied Images—Sometimes the way that backing images are created means that Core Animation is forced to make a copy of the image and send it to the render server instead of just sending a pointer to the original. This option colors such images blue in the interface. **Copying images is very expensive in terms of memory and CPU usage and should be avoided if possible.**

[Please see the image from FastCacheImage Demo project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGSZr.jpg)

Here all the images showing with blue overlay, mean they are copied. How to fix it?

Comment: On Simulator it shows Copied image. When we check on real device and used Insturments -> Core Animation -> Debug option, it shows proper.

Answer (score 0):

On Simulator it shows Copied image. When we check on real device and used Insturments -> Core Animation -> Debug option, it shows proper.
[Check image for Debug option on core animation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0so5q.png)